# Groups of transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, transformation, algebraic-groups

I tried to find literature and articles about groups of transformations, but mostly what I found is either about groups or about transformations.

Can you suggest me literature where groups of transformations are described. Specifically I'm interested in groups of linear and orthogonal transformations.

P.S. I'd prefer books and articles in Russian.

Comment: Any decent book in Lie groups **has** to talk about this

Comment: What level are you at? For example, Kobayashi wrote a book called *Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry* that is pretty advanced.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, what I need is a basic level _ definitions, the basic properties like addition, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mark A. Armstrong - *Groups and Symmetry* is definetely one of what you are looking for.

[http://www.amazon.com/Groups-Symmetry-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387966757](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387966757)

Comment: However you would like to have in Russian. I suppose there is a little chance that such kind of a source exists...

Comment: On the contrary, I imagine that many sources exist, but that most users of an anglophone web site like this one will not know what they are.